# Google indexing Wordpress wp-content directories and all internal files

Tags: google, wordpress, search-engine-indexing, directory, directory-listing

Recently I noticed that the total number of crawl pages have been increased. So I searched on google using `site:` and got several pages with a directory `wp-content`. I also checked Google Search Console, and there was huge hike in total number of crawled pages in 17th June 2018:

[image]

And on same date, website traffic dropped, if I am not wrong, Google crawled several unwanted pages under the `wp-content` directory and that might be the main issue, please see this screen shot (traffic started going down from 16th June 2018): 
[image]

Here is screen shot of `wp-content` directory indexed:

[image]

Kindly guide, how to stop google to stop crawling "wp-content" directory so that Duplicate and blank pages won't get crawled and at the same time, it should not affect crawling original pages.

Answer (score 2):

Fist of all, you should block the indexation through:

- robots.txt (using [disallow command](http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html))
- Server file configuration. If you are using Apache, you can [deny access to folders/files with .htaccess file](https://www.opentechguides.com/how-to/article/apache/115/htaccess-file-dir-security.html) (error 410).

Secondly, start deleting the URLs that have been already indexed from Google Index using [Google URL removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal)

Sadly, the above tool only lets you delete one by one. You can generate [410 error](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E410.html) to those URLs (the second option I commented before) but keep in mind that it's an advanced server configuration cause you just want to prevent the URLs from being indexed but you still need to access them as admin.

Comment: I have block the wp-content directory using robots then  google won't be able to crawl images, and will start showing several 404 error message. 

Same thing if i block it using .htaccess file.

Comment: Robots.txt it's not intended to remove URLs from the index, only to prevent crawling of URLs/folders/parameters/etc. If they have already been indexed, you need to remove them with the tool I mentioned before.

Comment: My advice is not to use either robots.txt or htaccess deny. Just edit the `.htaccess` and add `Options -Indexes` to the top of the file, done, sorted and it'll help secure other folders that you may not be aware off being indexed.

Comment: Did exactly same thing, Options - Indexed, thank Simon!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your server is creating an automatic page for all directories that lists all the files in that directory.

In Apache, this feature is provided by [mod_autoindex](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html).   If there is no, *index.html* file in the directory, this Apache module will automatically create a page that shows a directory listing.

One way to stop it from happening is to create blank index.html files in each and every directory.  Google won't index blank pages.  It would treat them as "soft 404" pages.

Another way is to disable directory listings.  This can either be done in your Apache *.conf* files or in your *.htaccess* file as long as `AllowOverides` is on.

```
Options -Indexes
```

For more examples see the "Directory Listings" section of https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryListings

Comment: Not sure about index.html page,tried this method long back but had bad impact:

searchenginejournal.com:

Potentially Misidentified as Soft 404
There are also cases wherein the page isn’t actually missing, but certain characteristics have triggered Google to categorize it as a missing page.

Some of these characteristics include a small amount or lack of content and having too many similar pages on the site.

These characteristics are also similar to the factors that the Panda algorithm tackles. The Panda update considers thin and duplicate content as negative ranking factors.